# Overwriting yoast's og:meta output?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I'm working on a blog with hundreds of old posts, and new posts being added daily. I can't change their flow of filling out the yoast meta tag for title. They want the og:title value to be something else though, a custom post_meta value from the same post.

How can I hook into yoast before they grab the title, and say "Don't use the yoast title, instead if we have a custom title filled out, use this one."

If this isn't possible, an alternative option would be to just output a duplicate og:title tag either before or after yoast, so that the yoast tag is ignored. Would I place my tag before or after to wipe out the yoast tag, and would there be a negative impact from having the two tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `wpseo_opengraph_title` filter:

```
function wpse_187763_wpseo_opengraph_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_singular() && $post = get_queried_object() ) {
        if ( $_title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_field_key', true ) )
            $title = $_title; // Override title with custom meta title
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_title', 'wpse_187763_wpseo_opengraph_title' );
```

**Update:** The single `=` is intended, since we're assigning the value & testing the expression at the same time. In other words, it's the same as:

```
$_title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_field_key', true );
if ( $_title )
    $title = $_title;
```

Comment: I'm going to test your code now. Shouldn't the if statements have double == signs, not single?

Comment: Nah it's intended (see revision).